# Three.js - How to scale a circle without scaling it's stroke?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I'm using a `THREE.Path` to create a Circular path and then using a `TubeGeometry` to use that Path to basically create a circle with transparent fill and a stroke whose thickness I can control. My question is, how can I scale up the Circular path at runtime?

Accessing the vertices through `mesh.vertices` results in a very weird result, because I'm accessing the Tube's Geometry, not the Path. If I change the path, then I have to create a brand new `TubeGeometry` and update the Tube with the new geometry by doing `mesh.geometry = newTubeGeometry`, and that just doesn't work at all. Scaling the Tube itself increases it's radius as well, so that's not the right solution either.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Just out of curiousity, why don't you use `THREE.TorusGeometry()` for that purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Just changing the geometry property does not work, you have to create a new instance of `THREE.Mesh`. You should also call `geometry.dispose()` on your old geometry because the renderer internally caches the corresponding `WebGLBuffer` objects. More information here:

https://discourse.threejs.org/t/changing-the-geometry-of-a-mesh/306

Comment: I thought of that, but since I need to make around 50 circles ( therefore tubes and paths and everything else that goes along with that ), and I need to scale them all up at runtime, it doesn't seem economical, performance-wise, to create and dispose of 50 meshes per frame, or 3000 meshes a second.

Comment: The other option is to update the vertices manually and trigger an update of the respective buffers. If you say that's not working, then I guess there is something wrong with your code. Can you show a live example of your current progress? https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/

Comment: It doesn't work because I don't know how to manually create a TubeGeometry.

Comment: But does this sound doable and economical? Making a new path and new tube geometry based on that and then just inserting those vertices into the tube's vertices. I think that the new TubeGeometry with the bigger circle path will have more vertices, so just placing the new ones won't work, if that's true

Comment: If you geometry grows, you have to create a new geometry anyway. The underlying buffers have a fixed size. They can not dynamically grow. I initially thought you could just manipulate the existing data without creating a new path. Independently, it's hard to tell you more without seeing your code or the desired visual results.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/filipetrovic/j4mx1x5g/
Here's the fiddle. If I have to make a new geometry I have to make a new mesh anyway.. Can I somehow get the true vertices of a scaled up circle?

Comment: You might need to look into `THREE.ShaderMaterial` for stuff like this.

Answer (score 0):

Just an example of how you can do that trick with `THREE.TorusGeometry()`:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 5, 10);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

var geometry = new THREE.TorusGeometry(5, 0.5, 8, 32);
geometry.rotateX(Math.PI * -0.5);
geometry.vertices.forEach(v => {
  v.initPosition = new THREE.Vector3().copy(v);
});
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: "red",
  wireframe: true
}));

scene.add(mesh);

var clock = new THREE.Clock();
var time = 0;

render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);

  time += clock.getDelta();

  geometry.vertices.forEach(v => {
    v // take a vertex
      .setY(0) // make it scalable in two dimensions (x, z)
      .normalize() // make a normal from it
      .multiplyScalar(Math.sin(time) * 2) // set the distance
      .add(v.initPosition); // add the initial position of the vertex
  });
  geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/91/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```